# Parsing Json with Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am having hard time getting a url from Json.
I have this :

```
if let dict = jsonResult as? [String: AnyObject] {
    if let d = dict["data"] as? [AnyObject] {
        for dict2 in d {
            let imgs = dict2["images"]
            print(imgs)
        }
    }
}
```

Till here its good, then every `imgs`  object print this :

```
({optionA =     {
        height = 180;
        size = 268905;
        url = "http://somthing.png";
        width = 350;
    };
    "optionB" =     {
        height = 180;
        size = 268905;
        url = "http://somthing.png";
        width = 350;
    };
    "optionC" =     {
        height = 180;
        size = 268905;
        url = "http://somthing.png";
        width = 350;
    };
```

I would like to go deeper into the url string, how would i do that ?
I am getting so many errors when trying to lop over `imgs`, in any way.
example  `for dic3 in images{}` gives errors that i cant loop over Anyobject, but if i make it NSArray i get another error.. I am lost ..

Comment: Although this won't directly help with the issue. I recommend you take a look at this: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Thanks, i just don't like using all this strange classes that I don't know whats inside. Prefer using my own code. Anyway I am almost there, just need the last lines..

Comment: Libraries such as SwiftyJSON will usually make it easier on the long run ;)

Comment: So you're going to eschew the entire Swift library because you don't know what's inside?  At some point you have to give up on NIH and build on the shoulders of giants.

Comment: `I am getting so many errors` ... `gives errors` ... `i get another error` ... You didn't mention a single specific error or pair it with any code that generates these errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it :

```
  let imgs = dict2["images"] as? NSDictionary
  let fixedH=imgs!.valueForKey("optionC")
  print(fixedH!.valueForKey("url"))
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to parse this in Swift would be like this -

```
let imgs:Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["optionA" :
                ["height": 180,
                  "size" : 268905,
                  "url": "http://somthing.png",
                  "width": 350],
            "optionB" :
                ["height": 180,
                 "size" : 268905,
                 "url": "http://somthing.png",
                  "width": 350],
            "optionC" :
                ["height": 180,
                  "size" : 268905,
                  "url": "http://somthing.png",
                  "width": 350]] 


func parseImgs(imgsDict:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
  let imgKeys = imgsDict.keys

  print("Number of keys = \(imgKeys.count)")

  for key in imgKeys {
    print("Key name - \(key)")

    guard let imgDict = imgs[key] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>,
        let height = imgDict["height"],
        let size = imgDict["size"],
        let url = imgDict["url"],
        let width = imgDict["width"]else {
        print("incorrect imgs format")
        return;
    }
  print("Height - \(height)\nSize - \(size)\nURL - \(url)\nWidth - \(width)")
  }
}

parseImgs(imgs)
```

I see that you have answered your question where you first convert it to NSDictionary, but that is kind of not needed because you are converting the Swift type ot Objective-C type just so that you can use it in the Objective-C way. Also avoid force unwraps like imgs! for data that you do not control.

Also I second Davie Brown's suggestion that you are probably better off using a third party library. Parsing JSON can get pretty complicated in Swift

Comment: I much prefer `[String: AnyObject]` syntax to this clunky `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`.

Comment: @nhgrif I would've preferred no type to be given at all, but playground was flaky and would not infer the type automatically.

Comment: Well, you have to specify it  for your function argument and your cast.